# RuntimeException Type mismatch. BOOLEAN for null using phoenix JDBC

Tags: java, spring-boot, hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm currently experiencing the following error:

```
Remote driver error: RuntimeException: org.apache.phoenix.schema.TypeMismatchException: ERROR 203 (22005): Type mismatch. BOOLEAN for null -> TypeMismatchException: ERROR 203 (22005): Type mismatch. BOOLEAN for null
```

While executing query using Java:

```
phoenixJdbcTemplate.queryForMap("SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalRecord From DEV.CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_FULL_NAME LIKE ?", Object[]{"%CUSTOMER"});
```

I'm using library phoenix-queryserver-client (4.10.0-HBase-1.2)

Note: this only happens when I use `LIKE` statement,

If trying to have full query below, didn't causing error:

```
phoenixJdbcTemplate.queryForMap("SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalRecord From DEV.CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_FULL_NAME LIKE '%CUSTOMER'");
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Phoenix, but you may want to include the definition of this `DEV.CUSTOMER` table.

Comment: I also new to Java, but query like `phoenixJdbcTemplate.queryForMap("SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalRecord From DEV.CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_FULL_NAME = ?", Object[]{"CUSTOMER A"});` is working, only `LIKE ?` is not working